# What Does |= Mean?

Tags: c++

I am reviewing some C++ code, and I've stumbled upon this piece of code: `|=`

I've Googled this and I can not find out what it means - can anyone help?

Comment: I would recommend you get a C++ book to use for reference.

Comment: You should learn *how* to google. `|=` obviously is operator. Just google c++ operators and you will find it in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x |= y` is equivalent to `x = x|y` if they're not overloaded to do something different.

This is called *compound assignment*: `e1 op= e2` form behaves as `e1 = e1 op e2` by default. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245297(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: This is the only correct answer so far, because it doesn't incorrectly assume that "and it's the bitwise or operator".

Comment: @H2CO3: It's just as much assuming when it says it's equivalent to `x = x|y`.  The operators are not tied together, and can be overloaded independently of each other.

Answer (score 3):

`foo |= bar;` is logically equivalent to `foo = foo | bar;` where `|` is the bitwise `or` operator or its overload.

Comment: True, with the addition that 1. `foo` is only evaluated once, and 2. it can be overloaded to do pretty much anything.

Comment: @Angew 100% agree, I'll edit the answer to better reflect his.

Answer (score 3):

This operator is a shorthand for `x = x | RHS`. Where the bar operator is bitwise inclusive or.

Answer (score 1):

Same as

```
x = x | y;
```

bitwise or operand.

Answer (score 1):

`|` is bitwise OR operation.  `|=` just assigns the bitwise OR of a variable with another to the one on the LHS.